# keeping values on php form after submit if error comes on form

Tags: php, jquery

This code i am using to select multiple values in dropdown with some jqueries

```
<script type="text/javascript">           
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#s1").dropdownchecklist();
        $("#s2").dropdownchecklist( {icon: {}, width: 150 } );
        $("#s3").dropdownchecklist( { width: 150 } );
        $("#s4").dropdownchecklist( { maxDropHeight: 150 } );
        $("#s5").dropdownchecklist( 
            { firstItemChecksAll: true, explicitClose: '...close' } );
        $("#s6").dropdownchecklist();
        $("#s7").dropdownchecklist();
        $("#s8").dropdownchecklist( { emptyText: "Please Select...", width: 150 } );
        $("#s9").dropdownchecklist( { textFormatFunction: function(options) {
            var selectedOptions = options.filter(":selected");
            var countOfSelected = selectedOptions.size();
            switch(countOfSelected) {
                case 0: return "<i>Nobody<i>";
                case 1: return selectedOptions.text();
                case options.size(): return "<b>Everybody</b>";
                default: return countOfSelected + " People";
            }
        } 
    });
    $("#pcity").dropdownchecklist({ emptyText: "Please select ...", width: 500 },{ maxDropHeight: 150 }, { forceMultiple: true
, onComplete: function(selector) {
    var values1 = "";
    for( i=0; i < selector.options.length; i++ ) {
        if (selector.options[i].selected && (selector.options[i].value != "")) {
            if ( values1 != "" ) values1 += ",";
                values1 += selector.options[i].value;               
        }
    }
    alert( values1 );
} 
, onItemClick: function(checkbox, selector){
    var justChecked = checkbox.prop("checked");
    var checkCount = (justChecked) ? 1 : -1;
    for( i = 0; i < selector.options.length; i++ ){
        if ( selector.options[i].selected ) checkCount += 1;
    }
    if ( checkCount > 3 ) {
        alert( "Limit is 3" );
        throw "too many";
    }
}
            });
```

I have this Code for city dropdown ,but when some error comes on form after submit ,values does not remain on form ,but with same code on other dropdowns in which i am not using above script values remain on form after submit if some error comes ,pls have some suggesions,thankyou.

```
<tr>
    <td> 
        <select name="pcity[]" id="pcity" multiple="multiple" style="display: none">
        <?php
            $pcitylist =  array(
        'Andaman and Nicobar' => array(
        'North and Middle Andaman', 'South Andaman', 'Nicobar'
    ),
    'Andhra Pradesh' => array(
        'Adilabad', 'Anantapur', 'Chittoor', 'East Godavari', 'Guntur', 'Hyderabad', 'Kadapa', 'Karimnagar', 'Khammam', 'Krishna', 'Kurnool', 'Mahbubnagar', 'Medak', 'Nalgonda', 'Nellore', 'Nizamabad', 'Prakasam', 'Rangareddi', 'Srikakulam', 'Vishakhapatnam', 'Vizianagaram', 'Warangal', 'West Godavari'
    ),
    'Arunachal Pradesh' => array(
        'Anjaw', 'Changlang', 'East Kameng', 'Lohit', 'Lower Subansiri', 'Papum Pare', 'Tirap', 'Dibang Valley', 'Upper Subansiri', 'West Kameng'
    ),
    );

    foreach ($pcitylist as $key => $pcitylist1)
    {
      echo '<optgroup label="'.$key.'">';
      foreach ($pcitylist1 as $finalCity) {
          echo '<option value="' . $finalCity . '"' . (isset($_POST['pcity']) && $_POST['pcity'] == $finalCity ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $finalCity . '</option>';
      }   
      echo '</optgroup>';
} 
?>
</select>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you can use html5 storage .. store information on onkeyup event and clear on form successful submit

Comment: i am new to html5 so don't know much about this event

Comment: can u explain code how can i use this event to keep value on form after submit if error comes,i searched but not able to get solution